# How to calculate the position for which the electrostatic potential is maximum?

Tags: electrostatics, potential

When we have a problem in which we have an expression for the electrostatic potential, such that its value varies with the position, how can we calculate the maximum value of the potential? Should I take the three partial derivatives (with respect to x, y, and z) and equal them to zero? In any case, would the value I get be different for the position for which the electric field is maximum?

All help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I take the three partial derivatives (with respect to x, y, and z) and equal them to zero?

Yeah, this is pretty much it. You should still take care to distinguish between local minima, local maxima, saddle points, and global minima and maxima, but if you're just looking for the global maximum and you have all the local critical points, then the one with the largest value will be the global maximum (unless the global maximum is at the boundary of your region).

It's important to note here that, because the electrostatic potential is a solution of the Laplace equation $\nabla^2\phi=0$ in the absence of electrical charge and therefore subject to the [maximum principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_principle), it *cannot* achieve a global maximum in the interior of any charge-free region. However, in the presence of electrical charge, this restriction is removed.

On a separate track,

> would the value I get be different for the position for which the electric field is maximum?

Yes, the positions where the potential and the electric field are maximized are generally different. This is easy to see by the fact that the electric field vanishes at the maxima of the potential, and similarly there is generally no constraint on the behaviour of the potential at maxima of the field strength.